# What does Prebuilt node builds mean?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install the [this](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) `node-printer` npm package. There is a pre built node build section under which there is:

```
npm install printer --target_arch=ia32
npm install printer --target_arch=x64
```

Googling pre build node built did not hep me much. Searching for `arget_arch=ia32` took me electron github issue page but I could not understand what it meant either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target_arch` option seems to be coming from [`node-pre-gyp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp) which [`node-printer` runs](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer/blob/master/package.json#L31) as `install` script [after it is installed](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description).

By "prebuilt", that means you won't have to build the C++ code yourself. It is pre-built (== built in advance) by the `node-printer` package.

Comment: Does this mean most npm package can be called pre build. I have never build C++ code myself when I install a npm package

Comment: Because not many NPM packages have C++ or any native language bindings, and JavaScript is "basically" a script language that is interpreted, not compiled.